# Socket.io client not receving emitted events when on a path behind an apache reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, apache, ionic-framework, socket.io

I am using socket.io in my node app. I also have an ionic app as a client. They are working when both are served from my machine under localhost. However today the node app was uploaded to a test server with apache. Apache has been configured to as a reverse proxy for the nodejs server under https://SERVER_IP/attendance and the client connects to the socket.io server, however no emitted events are getting trough to the client.

I will post the relevant code for the client, server and apache configuration:

**Ionic client code**

```
this.socket = io(this.socketUrl, {
    query: {
      sessionId: sessionId
    }
  });
  this.socket.on('connect', (data) => {
    console.log('connected', data);
  });
  this.socket.on('code received', (code) => {
    console.log('code received');
    this.code = code;
  });
```

**nodejs server code**

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  const querySessionId = socket.handshake.query.sessionId;
  connectedClients[querySessionId] = socket;
  socket.broadcast.emit('connect', 'connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    delete connectedClients[querySessionId];
  });
});

connectedClients[sessionId].emit('code received', newCode);
```

I use `connectedClients` to keep a list of clients and send the messages to the appropriate client, not everyone.

**apache config**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]

  ProxyPass        /socket.io http://localhost:3000/socket.io
  ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://localhost:3000/socket.io
  ProxyPass /attendance http://localhost:3000
  ProxyPassReverse /attendance http://localhost:3000
</VirtualHost>
```

The nodejs app is running on port 3000 on the server. The weird thing is that if I attempt to connect trough the port and not trough the /attendance path then it works and the emitted events are received by the client.